# Сделать правильный запрос SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Есть две таблицы  `products`, `reviews`.

```
products: id |product_name|image
reviews:  id |product_id  | rating(int)
```

Нужно получить

```
product_name | image | AVG(rating)
```

Вроде бы элементарно, но ...

```
select products.name, products.image, AVG(rating)
from products,reviews WHERE products.id=reviews.product_id;
```

> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression
>   #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'review.products.name'; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: А в чем проблема? Что не получается?)

Comment: Вроде бы элементарно , но ... select products.name , products.image ,AVG(rating) from products,reviews WHERE products.id=reviews.product_id;
ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'review.products.name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Не хватает Group by

Comment: Возможны ли записи, где `rating IS NULL`? если да - должны ли такие записи игнорироваться, считаться нулями, что-то иное? Что делать с записями из `products`, для которых нет ни одной записи в `reviews` - выводить, нет? если выводить - с каким значением рейтинга (ноль, NULL, иное)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно сработать

```
select
    pro.id, pro.name, pro.image, avg(rev.rating) from products pro
join reviews rev on pro.id = rev.product_id 
group by pro.id, pro.name, pro.image
```

Для подсчета среднего нужно использовать в запросе group by, подробнее можно почитать тут: https://oracleplsql.ru/group-by-sql.html