# Не могу составить правильный запрос SQL

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Есть две таблицы products, reviews.
Протупил , запутался ...

```
products: id |product_name|image
reviews:  id |product_id  | rating(int)
```

нужно получить

```
SELECT product_name,image, avg(rating) where product.id=1
```

Comment: вы вроде знакомы уже с `left join` и `group by`, в чем же проблема возникает?

Comment: да вроде бы написал - глянул вроде бы так, а не тут то было...

Comment: SELECT products.name ,avg(reviews.rating) from products left join reviews ON reviews.product_id=products.id group by products.name

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Сделать правильный запрос SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033213/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-sql)

Comment: неправильно вопрос поставил

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
 products.id,
 products.name,
 products.image,
 AVG(reviews.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM reviews JOIN products ON product_id=products.id
WHERE products.id=$id
```